# C++ nested namespaces error - expected type-specifier error

Tags: c++, namespaces

I've being searching for the solution of this problem, and I think it has something due to nested namespaces.

Bellow we have the relevant part of it:

**implementation.hpp** That is an implementation of an Interface

```
#ifndef IMPLEMENTATION_H
#define IMPLEMENTATION_H

#include "class_b.hpp"

namespace XPTO {
class Implementation : public XPTO::Interface {

    public:

        Implementation();
        ~Implementation() override;

        ReturnStatus
        initialize() override;

    private:

        CLASS_B::Class_B b; // namespace CLASS_B, class Class_B
    };
}
#endif
```

**implementation.cpp**

```
#include "implementation.hpp"

XPTO::Implementation::Implementation() {}

XPTO::ReturnStatus
XPTO::Implementation::initialize() {
    b = new CLASS_B::Class_B::Class_B(); 
    //namespace ClASS_B, class Class_B and constructor Class_B()
}
```

**class_b.hpp**

```
#ifndef CLASS_B_H
#define CLASS_B_H

namespace CLASS_B{

class Class_B {

    public:

        Class_B();
        ~Class_B();

        void initialize();
    };
}
#endif
```

**The error is**
error: expected type-specifier b = new CLASS_B::Class_B::Class_B();

The compiler is pointing to the namespace CLASS_B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this line is your problem:

```
b = new CLASS_B::Class_B::Class_B();
```

It only needs to be:

```
b = new CLASS_B::Class_B();
```

Assuming b is already declared somewhere else:

```
CLASS_B::Class_B()* b;
```

If you are allocating a block of memory with `new` you need a pointer to point to that block.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It really needs to be only `b = new CLASS_B::Class_B(); ` and I have to declare `b` as a pointer. Thanks also to @mastercat for the first response.

Comment: No problem. I wanted to add a couple notes though: If you kept the same declaration as you had originally "CLASS_B::Class_B b;" in your implementation.hpp. "b" would be allocated on creation of the class and deleted when that class is deleted so you would not need to use "new". In the implementation I gave you, you created the block of memory and set your pointer to the address of that block so it is good coding practice to run the command "delete b;" when you are done using that block.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the type of `b` in the declaration which must be specified before the identifier name. Try changing

```
b = new CLASS_B::Class_B::Class_B();
```

to

```
CLASS_B::Class_B *b = new CLASS_B::Class_B();
```

If you intended to initialize the private member b in the `initialize()` method then you would need to declare it as a pointer, since new returns a pointer.

Comment: Even though it is a private member of Class Implementation? Wouldn't it be a redeclaration of the same object?

Comment: Ah! I see. I've updated my answer. Can you try that ? If `b` is not pointer, then it's instantiated as part of the constructore of `XPTO::Implementation` (implicitly).

Comment: Thank you @mastercat . Your answer gave me the direction toward the solution. The only thing is that I need just to call `new CLASS_B::Class_B()`, as suggested by @i-funball